# Connecting Visual Studio2010 to local Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-2007

Just installed Sharepoint2007 and VS2010.
Made an empty Sharepoint project, and opened the server tab in VS.
I saw an option to make a Sharepoint connection.
I tried to, but it gave an error, saying that a Sharepoint server is not installed on the machine.
I can surf to Sharepoint's Central Admin, and all is well.
Do I need to have a website running, beside Central Admin, to connect VS, or should VS connect to Sharepoint as I have it (just after an installation)?

Comment: Maybe you need SharePoint 2010?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

John is right, you do need SharePoint 2010. 
Check out this msdn thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointdevelopmentprerelease/thread/da8de480-778b-4150-bd1b-c66bb75db042